# Problem with UV MAP and Unwrap

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I Created a low poly barrel with three cylinders. The first one I created is  the barrel shape, the other two are the rings around the barrel.

I have one problem with the UV MAP (Blender 2.82), when I select all vertices, Blender automatically creates streched a UV Map with 2 circles and 16 faces. I don't want this UV Map but I can't delete it.

I marked the barrel top, barrel bottom and all edges from one side with "Mark Seam" and after this I unwrapped my model. Unwrap creates something like 2 UV Maps in one, one over other, the first with 2 circles and 16 faces stretched and the second correct but I can't delete the first one.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "can't delete it"? In your picture, on the right side, where it says "UV Maps", click on the arrow, mark the UV Map and hit the Minus Button. Also, Blender doesn't align your UV maps automatically for you. You need to position those Islands by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing u and clicking unwrap should give you your new mesh with the seams that you have defined. You don't need to "delete" that one.

Answer (score 0):

UV map data can not be deleted from a layout. It can be 'reset' to 0, but given that nothing is created when unwrapping, deleting is not the correct terminology.

You have not marked seams for the rings, as a result blender falls back to what is already specified.

Create enough seams to make the rings unwrappable, then a single unwrap should give you everything you need.